# Not able to pass a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must be making a basic javascript error. My script is failing to pass a variable, and I can't figure out why. Here's the code, with comments.

```
var earth;

function loadWorld(world) {
    // loads the world from a Json file using php
    $.ajax("loadfile.php", {
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).done(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        //Here consul.log provides the expected results, confirming that the file has been loaded into the result.
        world = result;
        console.log(world);
        //Here too, properly transferred into world. 
    });
};

function button1() {
    loadWorld(earth);
    console.log(earth);
    //But here console.log tells me earth is undefined!
    showData(earth);
}
```

I've tried using earth as a global variable and simply assigning it in function loadworld(), like this:

```
earth = result;
```

I've also tried using a return function. But once I leave loadworld, earth is always undefined. Any ideas why?

Comment: can yoiu show a jsFIddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: What is `earth` supposed to contain? You need to give it a value before you pass it as a function parameter.

Comment: Why are you passing it as a parameter when `loadWorld` doesn't use its value? Assigning to the parameter doesn't change the original variable; Javascript is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference.

Comment: you haven't defined earth anywhere. define it before passing to `loadworld()` function.

Comment: 2 things here you cannot pass variables by reference in Javascript. secondly the ajax call is async so prob not complete by the time you console.log in button1 function

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because of asynchronously. Your last console.log called before your ajax request call done callback. Best solution is using callbacks

```
function loadWorld(world, success) {
  $.ajax( "loadfile.php", {dataType: "json", async: false} )
       .done(function (result) {     
          if(success) success(result);
        });     
};  

function button1 () {
    loadWorld(earth, function(result){
      //your callback logic  
      console.log(result)
      showData(result);
    }); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll work with this.

Comment: I thought I had avoided this by setting async to false, which I know is ugly. But it seems to be stuck at async anyways.

Comment: No problem)) I've recommended to you read https://github.com/BonsaiDen/JavaScript-Garden

Answer (score 0):

*(EDIT: As noted elsewhere, you also have an issue of the AJAX call not necessarily finishing before your function returns.)*

The problem is that JavaScript doesn't truly pass-by-reference. It effectively passes a copy of a reference. That means that if you pass an existing object into a function, you can make changes to it locally and it will affect the original. However, if you entirely overwrite the variable (by assigning a new object to it), the original will be unaffected.

In your case, you're assigning the result into `world`. All that does is affect the local `world` variable; it doesn't not overwrite `earth`.

See this question for more information: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

A better approach would be something like this:

```
var earth;

function loadWorld()
{
    // (loading code here...)
    return result;
}

function button1()
{
    earth = loadWorld();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that. It doesn't seem to work any better. The problem seems to be with ajax and asynchronicity.